# Cuda: is there any way to prevent other threads from changing a shared or global variable?

Tags: cuda, deadlock, atomic

say, I have a shared variable **checker** and the program works on different density ie. each thread will be working for one type of density

```
  __shared__ int Checker;
  int TID = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
```

so density on each thread be : density[TID]

****few calculations *****

so at some point, if the density increases than a threshold value, i need to change the value of checker.

something like:

```
 if( density[TID] > threshold)
        Checker=density[TID];
```

but if more than 1 thread satisfies the condition, then there might be a race condition, so how can i do that avoiding race condition.

I can use syncthreads and use for loop checking it 1 by 1, but that would be hugely serialized and slow.

I didnt find any atomic operation.
So, how do I avoid race condition here?

Comment: How can it modify something in global memory, if you are just reading from `density`, and `Checker` is local variable for each kernel, as I understood?

Comment: Some real code would be helpful. As written, it isn't at all clear what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: Ah, `checker` is shared, I see. Confused when I saw it next to `threadIdx`.

Comment: the program is huge and complex. So I just tried to show the problem in easier manner.

Comment: @LearningCuda: So make a compilable, simplified model version that captures the essential mechanism you are interested in implementing and add that to your question.

Comment: @learningcuda Not an exact answer to your question. But probably you may alter your program architecture in a way each thread will work with its separate `checker`. So, `checker` will be array, one element per thread. Once all `checker` elements for the step are calculated (all threads finished), you can calculate max value from the `checker`, for example.

Comment: If your goal is to gather the density of *any* thread above the threshold and you don't care about the identity of the thread, then it doesn't matter, just do what you already do. The race condition will not affect the correctness of your program. All the writes will be "collapsed" into one: *some* thread will write its result into `Checker`, although you don't know which one, and the others will have their write discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way to handle the race condition you mention is by using an atomic compare-and-swap operation, which is supported on CUDA capable GPUs for both shared and global memory [See atomicCAS in CUDA programming guide.](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomiccas).

```
__shared__ int Checker;
int TID = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadId
int localChecker;
// Do some ops
if( density[TID] > threshold) {
    localChecker = *(volatile int*)&Checker;
    if (atomicCAS(&Checker, localChecker, density[TID]) == localChecker) {
        // This thread won the write
    }
}
```